# WiFi router assigning different hostname despite sending gethostname()

Tags: linux, bash, wifi, dhcp, hostname

For some reason my wifi router is assigning an altered hostname to my linux device.

The hostname on my device is for example `shserver2`, my CLI login shows `me@shserver2:` and my `/etc/hostname` file concurs, and `$ hostname` returns `shserver2`.

Also my `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file contains the line `send host-name = gethostname();` so this should as I understand be sending the local hostname for the router to use.

The problem is that rather than recognising the name of the device as `shserver2` the router is persistently assigning the name `shserver` (without the appended 2).

I have previously had another device connected to the router as `shserver`, which currently isn't connected.  Both devices have generally had the same local addresses associated.  Since setting up `shserver2`, the router has generally assigned the same address (192.168.1.66).  And previously 192.168.1.65 was always directed to `sh_server`.  I have now reserved the address so accessing the device via SSH is possible which gets around one problem.

So my question is why would the router still be altering the hostname for the device.  This doesnt seem to occur with any other connection - phones, laptops, tv etc.

I got as far as the config files but otherwise drawing a blank on this one so hoping someone can help.

Comment: Thanks AB, I didn't know that though actually the server names are made up in this question as they relate to a work project. Worth knowing though the original ones didn't have an underscore, I've changed them in the question text to reflect so no underscore

Comment: It's possible the resolution of your problem is on the DHCP server and not on the DHCP client. You should check logs there. Or if there's no such option (eg: it's not really an Unix/Linux system with a CLI for the end user), maybe clean everything and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks AB, it's running through a household router so no cli for that other than the user options via 192.168.1.1. A reset seems to have corrected it but going to park this and put it down to the server side for now